# Locate internal missing values in time series (columns) and replace them by the average of available time steps (rows) in R

Tags: r

Using a `dataframe` made of time series in each column, and time steps in each row, the aim is to fill only the internal gaps in each time series (could be multiple gaps) using the mean of available value from the other time series, for the same time step.

example dataframe

```
test =  data.frame("ts1" = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1),
                   "ts2" = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2, NA, NA),
                   "ts3" = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 3))
```

On this example, first column, the first internal NA would be replaced by (2 + 3) / 2

I tried using something like this, but it does not work :

```
fixie <- function (df) {
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    foo = which(is.na(df[, i])) # select one time series (column) at a time
    
    tofill = NULL # empty object for storage
    
    for(j in 2:length(foo)){ # locate internal missing values in the time series
      tofill[i] <- ifelse(foo[j] == foo[j-1]+1, NA, foo[j])
    }
  
    tofill = tofill[!is.na(tofill)] # return the position of internal missing values 
    
    for(h in 1:length(tofill)){
      df[tofill[h], i] == mean(df[tofill[h],], na.rm = T) # replace by the mean of other ts
    }
  }
}

fixie(df = test)
```

There is probably an easier way to do it as well... Thanks for your inputs and comment :)

Answer (score 0):

one possibility:

```
test |>
    apply(MARGIN = 1,
        FUN = \(the_row) ifelse(is.na(the_row), mean(the_row, na.rm = TRUE), the_row)
        ) |>
    t() |> 
    as.data.frame()
```

```
   ts1 ts2 ts3
1  1.0   1 1.0
2  1.0   1 1.0
3  1.0   2 1.5
4  2.5   2 3.0
## truncated
```